# need guidelines in creating/updating related entities (is it possible with automapper?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC and would love to improve here. I used ASP.NET MVC + EF Code first approach. But I'm a little confuse on how to create/update related entites. So here's my scenario. Say,

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}

public class Stock
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ItemId { get; set; }
  public int StorageId { get; set; }
  public float Amount { get; set; }

  public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
  public virtual Storage Storage { get; set; }
}

public class Storage
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}
```

So an `Item` has a 1:many relationship with `Stock`. And `Storage` has 1:many relationship with `Stock`

In displaying them I used `Automapper` which worked perfectly. (Thanks to SO for helping me)

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is.. How to create/update entites? (Is it possible to used `Automapper` here?)

Say, in one `POST` it will add an `Item`, with `Stock`, and with selected `Storage`. A sample code would be great for reference.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use your DbContext?

Comment: Yes it did. It actually did an `INSERT` statement but only to the root entity. Think there's a way to also add the related entities in the root entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper is just a tool to map the properties of the `View Model` to/from your `Domain Model`.

The `View Model` is what you use in all of your Views, and your Domain Model is the underlying  business model which shouldn't be exposed to the Views.

This is what AutoMapper simplifies, it maps properties of these two models so that we don't have to keep on converting one model to the other.

---

Now moving on to creating / updating related entities...

Say we want to add new `Stock` using the navigation property on the `Item`.

```
Item item = this.DbSource.Items.First(itemEntity => itemEntity.Id == 5);

if(item.Stocks == null) item.Stocks = new Collection<Stock>();

item.Stocks.Add(new Stock
{
    StorageId = 3,
    Amount = 123F
});

this.DbSource.SaveChanges();
```

Another case that you just pointed out was having a new `Item` and X amount of `Stock` of that `Item`, which you want to store in the database in a single operation.

```
Storage storage = this.DbSource.Storages.First(storageEntity => storageEntity.Id == 3);

if(storage.Stocks == null) storage.Stocks = new Collection<Stock>();

Stock stock = new Stock
{
    StorageId = 3,
    Amount = 123F,
    Item = new Item
    {
        Name = "Redbull"
    }
};

storage.Stocks.Add(stock);

this.DbSource.SaveChanges();
```

Or if you have no data in your database and you want all 3 models posted in a single go...

```
Stock stock = new Stock
{
    Amount = 123F,
    Item = new Item
    {
        Name = "Redbull"
    }
};

Storage storage = new Storage
{
    Name = "It's a secret"
};

storage.Stocks.Add(stock);

this.DbSource.Storages.Add(storage);

this.DbSource.SaveChanges();
```

Also modify all of your Models with a constructor which initializes a `Collection` on all of your `ICollection` navigational properties, this way you can avoid the `NullReferenceException`

So for example modify the `Item` class to this

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.Stocks = new Collection<Stock>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}
```

---

Using the Item as root property

```
Collection<Stock> stocks = new Collection<Stock>();
Collection<Stock> stocks.Add(new Stock 
{
    StorageId = 123,
    Amount = 1000F
}); 

Item item = new Item
{
    Name = "Pizza",
    Stocks = stocks
}; 

this.DbSource.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes. This way will work. But what if you'll add an `Item` and `Stock` all at once in one `POST`. Think there's a way? Thank you for explaining `Automapper` by the way.

Comment: What if the root entity is `Item`. Will it apply the same idea?

Comment: Thanks man. It actually work. But kinda crowded my `Controller`. Anyhow, I can now move on. Thank you mate.

Comment: Last question, do you have any tips how to gracefully handle this things?

Comment: Your welcome, if you're happy with the answer, I would much appreciate it if you could select it as the accepted answer.

Gracefully? Could you elaborate on what you mean

Comment: I mean, I'm just wondering if there's a method or some way to achieve the same result but less on explicitly assigning them? That assigns automatically to each class' property?

Comment: That's where `AutoMapper` comes in... you would have a `ViewModel` for your `Form`, and inside `AutoMapper` you map the properties... You can find their documentation [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started), check it out it's really well written.

Comment: Oh so. You can assign `View Models` to `Domain Models`? Didn't know about that. I only thought `Domain Models` to `View Models`. Thanks.